# Can you vote Stack Exchange answers up or down during Chol Hamoed?

Tags: halacha, technology, chol-hamoed, stackexchange, voting

## Background

Stack Exchange websites, such as Mi Yodeya, include a "voting" feature. They let me click an "up arrow" icon to indicate that a post is useful, or a "down arrow" icon to indicate that it's not useful.

But voting requires a mouse click.

I suspect that clicking a mouse may be melacha. And so, like most types of melacha, I suspect that it is sometimes allowed, but sometimes forbidden, during Chol Hamoed.

## My questions

Can you freely upvote and downvote Stack Exchange posts during Chol Hamoed?  If so, why?

## Disclaimer

Please [ask your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: Then how about typing altogether?

Comment: @sam: [Ariel K](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/369/ariel-k) writes elsewhere that many consider typing to be melacha. But melacha is sometimes allowed on Chol Hamoed.

Comment: I am saying,the psak of clicking or typing should be in the same category.

Comment: When is it not permitted according to the ones who permit it?